# what is the meaning of this statement (a use of Hahn-Banach theorem)?

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to understand the following use of Hahn-Banach theorem where the goal is to prove a theorem like this:

Theorem: Let $\mu$ be a real valued $\sigma-$finite Baire measure on $X$... Let $E$ be an algebra of real valued essentially bounded Baire functions. Suppose $1\le p<\infty$ is given and $E\subset L_p(\mu)$. Let MANY OTHER CONDITIONS I OMITT. Then $E$ is dense in  $L_p(\mu)$.

The proof begins by stating:

"We show that if $I$ is a continuous linear functional on $L_p(\mu)$ such that $I(h)=0$ for every $h\in E$ then $I$ is idendically zero. This implies the closure $\bar E$ of $E$ in $L_p(\mu)$ is $L_p(\mu)$ by virutue of Hahn-Banach theorem."

and apparently describes a proof strategy. Could someone please help me understand it?There are a couple of things I wonder about:

(Q1) It seems that "the closure $\bar E$ of $E$ in $L_p(\mu)$ is $L_p(\mu)$" implies that $E$ is dense in $L_p(\mu)$. Why is that?

(Q2) I tried to check Hahn-Banach theorem on the internet, but there are so many versions around, and stated in a way I do not understand, and I do not have a clue which one is relevant (to do the reverse engineering process to understand the proof strategy). I would be greateful if someone could direct me to the right version. Which version is the right one? (and why?)

EDIT BEGIN:

Is seems that a consequence of the HB theorem is being used (taken from wikipedia, I am converting it directly to the present notation):

HBT consequence: If $L_p(\mu)$ is a normed vector space with linear subspace $E$ (not necessarily closed) and if z is an element of $L_p(\mu)$ not in the closure of $E$, then there exists a continuous linear map $\psi  : L_p(\mu) \rightarrow \mathbf R$ such that $\psi(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $E$ and $\psi(z) = 1$.

The key idea behind the proof is probably as follows: The point $z$ mentioned in the consequence can be found only if $\bar E\ne L_p(\mu)$, or more precisely if $\bar E\subset L_p(\mu)$.

It must be then conversely true that IF we are sure (can check somehow) that no such functional exists THEN there is no point in $L_p(\mu)$ which is outside of the $\bar E$, which in effect implies $\bar E=L_p(\mu)$.

What is confusing in the proof of the theorem is that the value of the functional is checked ONLY on $E$ and NOT on the full space $L_p(\mu)$. Exactly, that is what was bothering me all the time. I did not realize that when they say in the proof "...then $I$ is identically zero.", they probably mean **identically zero everywhere** (in the **full** $L_p(\mu))$.

**Did I get this right?**

EDIT END

(Q3) Is my understanding correct? Somehow the authors want to establish that there is no way to construct a non-zero linear functional on the space of $E$ that would produce zero (when applied to all $h\in E$). But isn't that sort of obvious? Why should that be an issue?

(Q4) If my understanding under (Q3) is correct, then what would happen if there would be a non-zero linear functional $J$ such that $Jh=0$ for every $h\in E$? Why would that prevent $E$ being dense?

All the help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

(Q1). Definition of the word "dense"

(Q2).
If $\overline{E}$ is not the whole space, we can define a non-zero bounded linear functional on a subspace with one more dimension... zero on $\overline{E}$, non-zero on one extra vector.  Then we can use the Hahn-Banach theorem to extend that to a linear functional on the whole space.

Comment: Many thanks for trying to help me out! Regarding your reply on (Q1): My perhaps naive understanding of "a dense class of functionsn E" is that any function can be approximated by a function from E. Closure is topological concept. How are these two ideas related? Is it hard to explain? (I am not a mathematician, as you probably guessed already).

Comment: Regarding your reply on (Q2), let me see if I am getting this right: If $\bar E$ is not the whole space, it means that some functions cannot be approximated by combining elements in $E$. ... I lost you completely on the rest.

Comment: OK...  It look like you will need to read some basic point-set topology if you want to understand papers with words like "closure" and "dense" in them.